# xml validation: validating a URI type

Tags: python, xml, validation, xsd

I'm using python's lxml to validate xmls against a schema. I have a schema with an element:

```
<xs:element name="link-url" type="xs:anyURL"/>
```

and I test, for example, this (part of an) xml:

```
<a link-url="server/path"/>
```

I would like this test to FAIL because the `link-url` doesn't start with `http://`. I tried switching `anyURI` to `anyURL` but this results in an exception - it's not a valid tag.

Is this possible with lxml? is it possible at all with schema validation?

Comment: is that `anyURL` or `anyURI` in your schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm pretty sure `xs:anyURL` is not valid. The [XML Schema standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI) calls it `anyURI`. And since `link-url` is an attribute, shouldn't you be using `xs:attribute` instead of `xs:element`?)

You could restrict the URIs by creating a new `simpleType` `base`d on it, and put a `restriction` on the `pattern`. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6

from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

schema_doc = etree.parse(StringIO('''
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="httpURL">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
            <xs:pattern value='https?://.+'/>
            <!-- accepts only http:// or https:// URIs. -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="a">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="link-url" type="httpURL"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
''')) #/
schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_doc)

schema.assertValid(etree.parse(StringIO('<a link-url="http://sd" />')))
assert not schema(etree.parse(StringIO('<a link-url="server/path" />')))
```